# Where does the QML default Button quick control get its colors from, if not QML SystemPalette?

Tags: windows, qt, button, qml, color-palette

I'm on a Windows 10 desktop system. I wonder why I can't find the colors in the QML SystemPalette, that I see being used by the QML default Button quick control.

The button appears to me in

- #e1e1e2 normal
- #e4f0f9 highlighted
- #cce4f7 pressed

But I can't find any of these in the active/inactive/disabled SystemPalette parts. In SystemPalette, a 'button' color is #f0f0f0, closer would be 'midlight' with #e3e3e3, and the only blue-ish stuff is 'highlight' with #0078d7.

Are they mixed together somehow?

---

UPDATE:

Perhaps important missing information: I'm using the Button from QtQuick.Controls 1.4.

If I have a look at the one from 2.0 it doesn't show colors from the SystemPalette either - but perhaps this can't be expected because of no pre-built native style for Qt Quick Controls 2?

---

UPDATE:

To clarify. It's more a question out of curiosity. No serious problems here. I'm just wondering whether there is a bug in QML SystemPalette, or even doubting it's usefulness at all. Is it an accumulation of not quite so correct constants?

Comment: Do you mean the Default style in Qt Quick Controls 2?

Comment: I'm using QtQuick.Controls 1.4, but a try of version 2 keeps the question alive. Updated the question...

Comment: Ok, so with Qt Quick Controls 1, which style are you using? Are you creating a QApplication or QGuiApplication in main()? Which version of Windows is it?

Comment: It's Windows 10. I've not yet instantiated QApplication or QGuiApplication (but will go with the latter). So far I'm just putting together something running in qmlscene only, under an ApplicationWindow.

Comment: If the application is using a `QApplication` then the version 1 QtQuick.Controls elements will use native styling, i.e. try to look as native as possible. That's why @jpnurmi was asking. You are definitely instantiating either `QApplication` or its base class `QGuiApplication` otherwise your program would not show anything at all

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question as you, and was unfortunately curious enough to dive through the source code to see how they did it.
For anyone else having the same question, it's difficult to create your own controls with the same stylistic flexibility as the built-in ones. Even if you bothered to (and I have), it won't be easily distributable, because you have to register your QML file against a namespace at runtime. In the end, it's easier to not bother with any of this and just upload a copy of your controls as people do in every other GUI framework.
The entire process is poorly documented, especially for those who want to start and end with .QML files.

Taking a snippet from their ToolBar.qml implementation:

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.2 as T
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
//...
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: 48
        color: control.Material.toolBarColor
        //...
    }
```

In brief, they implemented each default control three different times, and switch between them based on the particular settings of QQuickStyle.

In long, found in qquickstyle.cpp, much of the meat of what's going on downstairs is in the QQuickStyleSpec::Resolve() function. This sets the QQuickStyleSpec::style string to a folder in the installation directory, if you chose to set the style to one of the built-in options. An example folder path might be:
C:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2 for "Default", or
C:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\Material for "Material".

This path eventually gets passed to QtQuickControls2Plugin::registerTypes(), where QQuickStyleSelector.select() transforms the relative path into an absolute path and performs a branching search for the QML file we want to register. With the absolute path, uri (QtQuick.Controls), and whatever version number we want, we can now register the QML file under the uri like so:

```
qmlRegisterType(QUrl("file:///C:/absolute/file/path/FancyControl.qml"), "QtQuick.Controls", 2, 1, "FancyControl");
```

For your convenience, I decomposed the function calls into constant literals so you know exactly what is going on. Note that it is actually impossible to register under "QtQuick.Controls", as the function claims that particular namespace is already registered. Whatever that means.

This is all happening at runtime, which makes such a thing all that much more difficult to distribute--you would have to write a library to simplify registration.

I imagine the reason they did it this way is because of how different each style is. Material Design is much more complicated and requires use of OpenGL shaders, as well as other settings specific to Material Design that the others don't have. So to provide the illusion that multiple styles with completely different underlying content were one control, they must have had no choice but to play Pachinko with .QML files. A sort of twisted take on the simple Interface.

My recommendation is to forget any of this exists and distribute minimally effective copies of your controls, as people do in every other GUI framework.

Comment: When you say "create your own controls with the same stylistic flexibility as the built-in ones", what exactly are you trying to do? With regards to the documentation being poor, it would be great to have feedback that describes exactly what you think should be improved: https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: At the time of writing, I was trying to figure out how to create a control that can adapt to the selected style--Material, Universal, or Default--as necessary because whatever technique was being used might be useful for general purpose control design. When I say that the documentation is poor in this regard, I mean to say that while the functions to register QML files namespaces are somewhat documented, there is nothing in the way of tying them together. It wouldn't have been possible for me to figure out how to do it without reverse engineering, because the Style docs don't talk about this.

Answer (score 0):

Most QtQuick 2 controls have a `palette` property where you can configure the colors of the current item as well as its children. Here, I set the `palette` for the `Page` and the `Button` inherits it:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    palette.button:     "lightsteelblue"
    palette.buttonText: "purple"
    palette.mid:        "orange"
    Button {
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAAw3icbY1BCsIwEEX3OUXIAXqALnXj0oIXSHVIB6eZkP6AIL17TdON4t/N5837PCfNsAOGwven4a+zO2tEVlnM1Qeyb2M/SV4IoG4sgMa+VtYJhwkLiGSUQu4PeKMXeutSyUl+gJkfTVNNmn0MB3DaP4/dGjTJhUS0IatZN982PHA=)